# How can use my own styles in klokantech/openmaptiles-server docker container?

Tags: tiles, docker, openmaptiles

If I use [klokantech/openmaptiles-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/openmaptiles-server/) docker-container it work well. I can download style and change it like in [Upload Style to Mapbox Studio](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/style/mapbox-studio/) described.

But how can I use the new style.json in my klokantech/openmaptiles-server container? In docker cmd-line is the `-v $(pwd):/data` argument for an external data directory. There no hint in klokantech/openmaptiles-server documentation of how using "data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server
2. call wizzard http://localhost:8080
3. choose "Advanced options" on the "Styles" page
4. upload your style

Comment: How to add my own icons? (which is not the same as sprites!)?